# How to get number of elements in byte array?

Tags: java, arrays

As everyone already knows, Java allocates the size of array upon declaration. meaning that if I define array like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
```

the `buffer.length` will return 10. However, my question is, how can I find out how many elements are populated. I am populating elements from an `InputStream` so I never know how many elements will be there.

I know that allocated array positions which are empty will be `0` but what if I am getting zero values from the `InputStream` as well, mixed together with normal values?

Comment: You can't. Just store the amount of bytes you have read in a variable. InputStream.read() returns the number of bytes read. If you posted your code, we could tell you how to write it better.

Comment: Typically the methods you would use to read _into_ a `byte` array would either return an array containing only actually read content or would return the number of bytes read.  So your use case is an edge one at best.  As @JBNizet mentioned, you never showed us any code.

Comment: @JBNizet, you were right. I can get the actual size doing InputStream.read(). It works! Super. Please answer my question so I may mark it as correct.

Comment: @OndrejTokar I hope you are aware that by contract you must not rely on the `read` method to read as many bytes as available, but you have to do this in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Just store the amount of bytes you have read in a variable. [`InputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) returns the number of bytes read:

> Returns:
>
> the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-populate the array with some *invalid* value that is not expected to be produced by the `InputStream`. However, this depends on the `InputStream`s content, so picking a generic default value is not really easy.

Another option for you is to use some collection, like `List<Byte>` or `Set<Byte>` (if you need uniqueness) - in this case the number of populated elements will simply be the size of the collection and if you really need an array at the end, you could easily produce one from the content of the collection.

Comment: His problem doesn't really occur with the standard IO to byte array procedures, AFAIK.

Comment: The prepopulation thing would be amazing, problem is the type of the array is byte... which doesn't give me many unique options ;/. I think I could use a collection maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at this piece of code:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("fileName"));
int cntReadBytes = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[10];
        while((i = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            bytes[cntReadBytes] = i;
            cntReadBytes++;
        }
        System.out.println("You have read total: " + cntReadBytes + " bytes" );
```

as you can see in the while loop condition I make comparison of inputstream return and `-1`, when the return value is different it means I have more data to read, when it reaches the end of file it will return `-1`. So the value of `cntReadBytes` will be the number of iterations, i.e. successfully read bytes.

Or if you are free to use List, you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Reading one byte at a time is really inefficient. And what's that undeclared `res` variable?

Comment: I know it is not such a efficient approach but it's the only way, that's how I do it. If you know better way please post it.

Comment: Err, yes, use `InputStream.read(byte[])` instead of `InputStream.read()`. Read my answer. Read the javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of bytes passed through the InputStream, e.g. by using Apache Commons [CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html). Or you could extend FilterInputStream yourself, if you don't have Apache Commons.